# Mocking nested functions with jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I have this code;

```
import { initRepo, getOrganisationsRepo } from "Repositories";
import logger from "Logger";

export const getOrganisations = async (event) => {
  try {
    await initRepo();
    const repo = await getOrganisationsRepo();
    const data = await repo.getOrganisations();

    // 200: Response is an array & is not empty
    if (Array.isArray(data) && data.length)
      return { statusCode: 200, body: JSON.stringify(data) };

    // 404: Response is an array and is empty
    if (Array.isArray(data) && !data.length) return { statusCode: 404 };

    return { statusCode: 400 };
  } catch (error) {
    const errorMessage = error?.message || "error fetching organisations";
    logger.error({ event: "org_get_failed" }, errorMessage);

    return { statusCode: 400, body: errorMessage };
  }
};
```

I want to mock the following calls using jest, as this is DB logic that I do not want to test here.

```
await initRepo();
const repo = await getOrganisationsRepo();
const data = await repo.getOrganisations();
```

And I would like to mock the return value of `repo.getOrganisations();`

I am not quite sure exactly how to do this. I can mock `getOrganisationsRepo` but then I'm not sure how to mock the return value of `repo.getOrganisations()`

This is pretty much as far as got with the mocks, these work, and I can test that the two functions have been called once, etc.

```
jest.mock("Repositories");
mockRepositories.initRepo.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve());
mockRepositories.getOrganisationsRepo.mockImplementation(() =>
  Promise.resolve()
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jest.mock()` will mock the `Repositories` module and its functions exported will be auto mocked. This means the second mock factory function is optional. Since `initRepo` function is already mocked and has no resolved value, you don't need to mock it again. We should focus on mocking the `getOrganisationsRepo` function and its resolved/rejected value.

E.g.

`getOrganisations.js`:

```js
import { initRepo, getOrganisationsRepo } from './Repositories';

export const getOrganisations = async (event) => {
  try {
    await initRepo();
    const repo = await getOrganisationsRepo();
    const data = await repo.getOrganisations();

    // 200: Response is an array & is not empty
    if (Array.isArray(data) && data.length) return { statusCode: 200, body: JSON.stringify(data) };

    // 404: Response is an array and is empty
    if (Array.isArray(data) && !data.length) return { statusCode: 404 };

    return { statusCode: 400 };
  } catch (error) {
    const errorMessage = error?.message || 'error fetching organisations';

    return { statusCode: 400, body: errorMessage };
  }
};
```

`Repositories.js`:

```js
export async function initRepo() {
  console.log('initRepo real implementation');
}
export async function getOrganisationsRepo() {
  console.log('getOrganisationsRepo real implementation');
}
```

`getOrganisations.test.js`:

```js
import { getOrganisations } from './getOrganisations';
import { getOrganisationsRepo } from './Repositories';

jest.mock('./Repositories');

describe('68805379', () => {
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  test('should return array data', async () => {
    const repo = {
      getOrganisations: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce([{ id: 1 }]),
    };
    getOrganisationsRepo.mockResolvedValueOnce(repo);
    const actual = await getOrganisations();
    expect(actual).toEqual({ statusCode: 200, body: JSON.stringify([{ id: 1 }]) });
    expect(getOrganisationsRepo).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(repo.getOrganisations).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/68805379/getOrganisations.test.js (9.919 s)
  68805379
    ✓ should return array data (5 ms)

---------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                 | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
---------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files            |   63.16 |    21.43 |      50 |      60 |                   
 Repositories.js     |      50 |      100 |       0 |      50 | 2,5               
 getOrganisations.js |   66.67 |    21.43 |     100 |   63.64 | 13-19             
---------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.002 s
```

P.S. I use relative path `./Repositories` instead of module alias when using `jest.mock()`, if you have been set up module alias, then you should use module alias as the module name for `jest.mock()`.

Comment: This worked an absolute treat. Thank you.